# Cache a DB table in a .Net 2.0 app. What's the fastest way of accessing it?

Tags: c#, .net, database, select, datatable

I have a (static) table which I need to access very frequently. Therefore I cache it at run time.

For now  I'm using a DataTable to store the information and the Select() to retrieve it (the filtering is usually spread over 2 or 3 columns). But this appears to be very (!) slow and is a major bottleneck.

Therefore: What is the best way of caching a DB table (in .Net 2.0) and how to access it the fastest?

---

[edit 1]

```
DataTable cache = new DataTable();
cache.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
cache.Columns.Add("data_id", typeof(int));
cache.Columns.Add("data", typeof(string));
cache.Columns.Add("value", typeof(float));
```

Eg:

```
DataRow[] result1 = cache.Select("id = 1 AND data_id = 2 AND data = 'some data'");
DataRow[] result2 = cache.Select("data = 'some other data'", "data desc");
```

---

[edit 2]

Having in mind the suggestion from @MichaelPerrenoud, I ended up implementing a Dictionary. Please have in mind that this design is with respect to the structure of the DB table that I needed cached.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<NewObject, float>> cache;
class NewObject {int id; int data_id;}
```

This way the **cache** has as the [key] the *data* and as the [value] a new Dictionary. And this latter has as the [key] the *id + data-id* and as the [value] the *value*.

In accessing the data, this Dictionary is **~%90** faster than the DataTable.

Comment: Can you show how you are currently implementing this DataTable / usage?

Comment: Please provide examples of the filters - that is the ***only way*** we would ever be able to understand the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think a good solution for you would be something like this. I'm making the assumption that you have the `DataTable` after you **initially** get the data.

***DISCLAIMER: I have not compiled this code - it's a concept - you may need to fix some syntax.***

```
Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> CacheData(DataTable t, params string[] fields)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> cache = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();
    StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataRow r in t.Rows)
    {
        key.Clear();
        foreach (string f in fields)
        {
            if (key.Length > 0) { key.Append("_"); }
            key.Append(Convert.ToString(r[f]);
        }

        if (!cache.ContainsKey(key.ToString())) { cache.Add(key.ToString(), new List<DataRow>()); }
        cache[key.ToString()].Add(r);
    }
    return cache;
}
```

Now, you can store those dictionaries any way you see fit and then pull data out of them when you need to, so for example if you needed to handle the first example it might look something like this to create the cache:

```
CacheData(table, "id", "data_id", "data");
```

and then to get data out you would build a string like this:

```
string key = "1_2_some data";
```

and pull the list of rows out of the dictionary like this:

```
dictionary[key];
```

and that would return a `List<DataRow>` for you to use.

---

But, you'll only have to do this ***one time*** and then leverage those dictionaries over and over.

Comment: Thank you fro the suggestion. This is very interesting. But: (1) the table has several hundreds of thousands of rows; (2) per each (let's say) "id"&"data_id"&"data" combination, I will access the table once or twice in the app's lifetime.

Comment: @Yeseanul, then you ***by definition*** don't need caching if you're only going to access the table once or twice - run a query against the database. But you said `which I need to access very frequently`, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes, you are right (**by definition**). But, as I said, the table has several hundreds of thousands of rows. And I need to access 50% or 70% of those (each one once or twice, usually twice). Avoiding hitting the DB is a must because speed is crucial. This is why I'm using an in-memory copy of the table.

Comment: To your suggestion, I represented the cached data as a Dictionary. The solution that I've chosen is in _[edit 2]_.

Comment: @Yeseanul, that's fantastic! The increase is exactly what I expected. And this is what programming is all about - a concept - not necessarily a literal implementation. There could have been things in your question that I couldn't derive, but the concept worked the same.

Comment: Exactly! Nevertheless, isn't there a generic solution for this? Let's say the table has 10 or 15 columns and therefore is cumbersome to take the Dictionary approach. Is using a self-contained, embeddable database (using e.g., SQLite) the only solution?

Comment: @Yeseanul: Microsoft provides some pretty good built in mechanisms via the AppFabric Caching libraries - but it's a huge overkill for what you need. For example, we leverage AppFabric Caching across numerous nodes because we do millions of transactions per day and are reading lists of data 100's of 1,000's of times per day. We need to be able to get to them centrally, and we need fail overs, we can't be down. But you have very complex mechanisms for refreshing the cache when those lists change and such as well. **Caching is always a custom solution based on your needs.**

Comment: "Caching is always a custom solution based on your needs" - yes, indeed. Thanks for your help and insights.